# Cassandra Partitioning: collisions in partitioning key in a table

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-2.1

We know that nodes in Cassandra hold tokens. So in a 4 nodes cluster say node1 is 25, node2 is 50, node3 is 75 and node4 is 100. This also means that node1 is responsible for the range 0-25. Now this means that if any partitioning key's hash results in a token value say 3 then that record with that partition key goes to node1. So tokens basically determine data locality. Now, in a table T1 where you have a primary key ((COL1), COL2) with partition key COL1 plus clustering columns COL2 defined, is there any chance that there could be two records with different partition key values (note: partition key column is the same COL1 but the value is different for the two records say v1 and v2) but when hashed they result in the same token and therefore same node but two different partitions? In brief, can two partition key values v1 and v2 (from two records of course) of a partition key COL1 in a table T1 have the same hash value i.e. token (and obviously therefore same node but two different partitions)? Conversely put, can 1 token be arrived at from two different values of the same partition key column? If yes, Can we therefore infer that the ratio  between partition key value to token is n:1 and the ratio between node:token is 1: n?

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: mumur3 partitioner generates unique hash values. therefore two partition can not have same token number.